# Ubuntu 17.04 won't boot on HP Envy x360 laptop

Tags: 17.04, radeon, amd-graphics

When I try to load the Live USB of Ubuntu 17.04, it gives some distorted lines across the screen, and the following error:

[image]

[image]

Anyone know of a solution or a fix? Booting with the 17.10 daily iso via Live USB DOESN'T produce this issue, so it seems to only be related to 17.04.

PC SPECS
HP Envy x360 2-in-1 laptop
Model: bq021dx
Graphics: AMD Radeon R7

Comment: Try booting with the `nomodeset` parameter and see if it boots then.

Comment: @heynnema, that did it! I had to boot in non-UEFI mode, press F6 for additional boot options, then check/select "nomodeset", then press ENTER. Took a little while, but it booted into the Unity desktop. Thanks, appreciate it!

Comment: If you have Windows on the machine, it's probably installed in UEFI mode, and you should boot/install in the same mode.

Comment: If I'm looking to install over Windows, is there any reason I should still boot in UEFI mode?

Comment: You should keep Windows, and install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration. You may need Windows in the future, for things like BIOS/UEFI updates, and Windows only apps... and if you need vendor support.  And if Windows is installed in UEFI, you should install Ubuntu the same way.

Comment: Completely understand, and I appreciate the suggestions. Thanks also for the work-around! Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by heynnema in the OP, I found the solution to at least get it to boot to the desktop:

(1) Switch the BIOS to boot to non-UEFI mode, then boot to USB
(2) Press F6 at the purple screen for additional boot options
(3) Enable/check/select the "nomodeset" option
(4) Press ESC to go back, then ENTER to continue boot.

Success!